# How to convert array of decimal strings to array of integer strings without decimal and vice-versa

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve the following. How to get the desired output as below?

```
var arr=["1.00","-2.5","5.33333","8.984563"]

    Desired output: arr=["1","-2","5","8"]

    and vice-versa float to int.
```

Comment: loop, indexOf() to find "." then substr() to read up to it.

Comment: Why are these strings when you want to cast floats to integers?

Comment: `arr.map(e => (~~e).toString());` but note that for such a vague description on how the transformation should occur and no ideas by yourself this is just the shortest answer i could think of that fulfills your example. `~~` is imho not good style.

Comment: Or `arr.map(x=>parseInt(x,10)+"")`

Answer (score 1):

You could save the sign, apply flooring to the absolute value, put the sign back and convert the result to a string. Map the whole stuff to a new array.

*Vive versa* does not work, because you loose information while using integer numbers.

```js
var array = ["1.00", "-2.5", "5.33333", "8.984563"],
    result = array.map(v => ((v >= 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(v))).toString());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=["1.00","-2.5","5.33333","8.984563"]
arr.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    array[index] = parseInt(item)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr=["1.00","-2.5","5.33333","8.984563"]

var output = arr.map(n => Math[n < 0 ? "ceil":"floor"](n).toString() ) 

console.log( output )
```

Rounding to the closest value to zero using `Math.ceil()` for negative numbers and `Math.floor()` for positive numbers.